# What is parameter shear range in ImageDataGenerator TensorFlow Keras to be mathematically defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

In data augmentation using Tensorflow there is a parameter called shear_range which is Shear Intensity (Shear angle in counter-clockwise direction in degrees) with input as Float. What I curious about is how Float can be as input to be an angle of shear in degrees?

I tried to learn Image Classification using TensorFlow Keras and found data augmentation which one of the it is ImageDataGenerator. In ImageDataGenerator there is parameter called shear_range with input in Float but the changes are in degrees. I want to know how Float as input can turned into angle

Comment: An angle does not have to be an integer. Angles are not a discrete set of values.

Answer (score 1):

Shear transformation slants the shape of the image. This is different from rotation in the sense that in shear transformation, we fix one axis and stretch the image at a certain angle known as the shear angle. This creates a sort of ‘stretch’ in the image, which is not seen in rotation. shear_range specifies the angle of the slant in degrees.